# Quicksort wont sort array correctly

Tags: java, data-structures, quicksort

I am trying to practice how to run a quick sort on an array. However, when I run my program the array isn't fully sorted(see output) and I am not totally sure where the problem might be. I think the error might be in the partition method.

```
package qs;
import java.util.Random;

public class Qs {

public static final Random ran = new Random();
public int[] array;
public int elements;

public Qs(int[] a){
    this.array=a;
    this.elements=a.length;
}

public void swap( int i, int j){
    int temp=array[i];
    array[i]=array[j];
    array[j]=temp;
}

private int partition(int[] a, int start, int end){

    int index = start+ran.nextInt(end - start + 1); //set random index pivot value   
    int pivot = a[index];//sets the random pivot value
    swap(index, end); // puts random pivot value at the end of array
    for (int i= index = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (a[index]<pivot) {
            swap(index, i); 
            index++;
        }
    }
    swap(index, end);
    return index;
}

private void qsort(int[] a, int start, int end){
    if(end > start){
        int index = partition(a,start,end);
        qsort(a, start, index - 1);
        qsort(a, index + 1, end);
    }        
}

public void sort(){
    qsort(array, 0, elements-1);
}

public void print(){
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] a ={5,23,69,55,448,3,78};        
   Qs q = new Qs(a);

   System.out.println("Original Array");
   q.print();
   q.sort();
   System.out.println("Sorted Array");
   q.print();

    }

}
```

Output from this program:

Original Array 
5 23 69 55 448 3 78 
Sorted Array 
3 5 23 55 78 69 448 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: You will need to step through your code using a debugger and figure it out.

Comment: Don't do something like that: `int i= index = start;`. It is horrible to read. Separate these assigments and the next guy who reads your code will thank you.

Comment: @JulianL. The funny thing is this is how my Computer Science teacher does it which kind of scares me.. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small mistake:

```
if (a[index]<pivot) {
```

should be:

```
if (a[i]<pivot) {
```

Looks fine for the rest.